# Magento Drop Down cities list based on Provinces/Regions

Tags: ajax, magento

I am building a drop down cities list in Magento. The drop down list updates depending upon the province/region selected. I have followed a [tutorial](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-city-as-dropdown-option-in-checkout-billing-shipping-address/). The problem is that i need to make ajax calls to the Data helper to get the cities based upon the province.

Magento does it itself as it updates the regions/provinces based upon the country drop down. I have searched a lot but could not find the code in which Magento fires an ajax call.

Can some body here guide me how does Magento makes the ajax call or how should i do an ajax call in magento frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `RegionUpdater` that can be found in the varien form js `/js/varien/form.js`

This is used in the registration form as follows:

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
<?php endif; ?>
```

The RegionJson is a json object of all the possible regions. and uses the following options:

1. id of the country element on the form,
2. id of the region text element,
3. id of the region select element,
4. possible region options in json format,
5. option to disable the region,
6. id of the zip code element,